# Inline error message still displayed after the user adds text to input fields

Tags: javascript, html, keydown, submit-button, queryselector

When users click submit, I've coded an error message to appear under each input field that is missing a value using DOM selectors. I also disabled the email file that opens when submit is clicked, using `preventDefault()`.

However, when the user types into the text area, the messages don't disappear. I tried using a 'keydown' event, but I couldn't get it to work.

HTML code:

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">

        <form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com">
            <fieldset>

                <legend>Personal details</legend>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        Full name:
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="errormsg" id="nameerrormsg">Please enter your name above</p>

                <p>
                    <label>
                        Street Address:
                        <input type="text" name="streetaddr" id="streetaddr">
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="errormsg" id="addrerrormsg">Please enter your street address</p>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit it!" class="submitIt" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
        </form>
        <br>

        <script src="inline-error.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <div class="returnHome">
            <a href="javascript:history.back()">Return Home</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Javascript code:

```js
var submitIt = document.querySelector(".submitIt");
submitIt.addEventListener("click", function checkForm(event) {
    var fNameInput = document.querySelector("#fullname")
    var streetAddInput = document.querySelector("#streetaddr")
    if (fNameInput.value == "") {
        var nameErrorMsg = document.querySelector("#nameerrormsg").style.display = "block";
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (streetAddInput.value == "") {
        var addrErrorMsg = document.querySelector("#addrerrormsg").style.display = "block";
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: You only have code to show the error messages, but none to hide them again. That should lead you to a rather obvious solution ;-).

Answer (score 0):

To see an immediate result in the code in its current state, hide the error messages before checking the input values.

```js
var submitIt = document.querySelector('.submitIt');
submitIt.addEventListener('click', function checkForm(event) {
    var nameErrorMsg = document.querySelector('#nameerrormsg');
    var addrErrorMsg = document.querySelector('#addrerrormsg');

    nameErrorMsg.style.display = 'none';
    addrErrorMsg.style.display = 'none';

    var fNameInput = document.querySelector('#fullname');
    var streetAddrInput = document.querySelector('#streetaddr');

    if (fNameInput.value == '') {
        nameErrorMsg.style.display = 'block';
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (streetAddrInput.value == '') {
        addrErrorMsg.style.display = 'block';
        event.preventDefault();
    }       
});
```

Having said that, here are some additional suggestions:

- Use CSS for styling elements (not JavaScript)
- Discourage inline JavaScript
- Store DOM elements outside the scope of the event listener so you don't have to query the DOM every time you click
- Consider utilizing the `required` attribute on the `input`s for a quick win on styling

So...

```html
<!-- form.html -->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal details</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="fullname">Full name:
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" required>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="errormsg" id="nameerrormsg">Please enter your name above</p>
                <p>
                    <label for="streetaddr">Street Address:
                        <input type="text" name="streetaddr" id="streetaddr" required>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="errormsg" id="addrerrormsg">Please enter your street address</p>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit it!" class="submitIt">
        </form>
    </header>
    <button id="returnhome">Return Home</button>
    <script src="inline-error.js"></script>
</body>
```

```css
/* form.css */
input:valid {
    border: none;
}
input:invalid:required {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.errormsg {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```js
// inline-error.js
var submitIt = document.querySelector('.submitIt');
var nameInput = document.querySelector('#fullname');
var nameError = document.querySelector('#nameerrormsg');
var addrInput = document.querySelector('#streetaddr');
var addrError = document.querySelector('#addrerrormsg');
var returnHome = document.querySelector('#returnhome');

returnHome.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.back();
});

submitIt.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const nameValue = nameInput.value;
    const addrValue = addrInput.value;

    if (!nameValue || !addrValue) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!nameValue) {
        nameError.classList.add('show');
    } else {
        nameError.classList.remove('show');
    }

    if (!addrValue) {
        addrError.classList.add('show');
    } else {
        addrError.classList.remove('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, it's much appreciated. I've made amendments to the code in order for it to work in its current state, but one part is confusing me - why do I need to hide the text with JS before if I've already hidden it using CSS? (Sorry, I didn't incl. CSS code in initial post). 

Thanks for the additional notes as well, plenty of topics to learn there lol!